# navbar-toggler shifts upwards when I press it

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am coding navigation menu for my website using Bootstrap 5.3. However, I faced a weird problem with navbar-toggler. The button shifts upwards when clicked. Moreover, CSS rules don't affect my collapse menu instantly, which doesn't look smooth. For few second after collapsing the menu has no styling at all...

Here is  from my HTML file

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">

    <div class="container-fluid justify-content-center">

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Переключатель навигации">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="main.html" class="nav-link">Главная</a></li>

          <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Новости</a></li>

          <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Тома</a></li>

          <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Поддержать автора</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </nav>
```

Here is CSS rules I am trying to use

```
nav{

    height: 100px;
    background: rgb(34,34,34);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(34,34,34,1) 0%, rgba(27,27,27,1) 100%);
    
}

.navbar > .container-fluid {

    padding: 0px;

}

nav > .container-fluid > .collapse > ul > li {

        padding: 0 30px;
    
    }

    .collapse{

        background: rgb(34,34,34);
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(34,34,34,1) 0%, rgba(27,27,27,1) 100%);
        margin-top: 50px;

    }

    .collapse ul li a{

        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px 0px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #7a7a7a;

    }
```

I expect navbar-toggler to stay in the center of navigation bar and smoothly show the collapse menu, which uses CSS styling instantly.

UPD: The problem is solved. It occurred because I didn't pay enough attention while coding, however I will share my solution.

It was a mistake to use "collapse" class in order to style the menu. When you press toggler-button, menu's class changes to the "collapsing" for a second. That's why transition was broken.

Also, the menu had no absolute positioning, so button was moved upwards every time I open the menu to create some extra space for it.

Comment: Can you create a code snippet reproducing the problem and including Bootstraps JS/CSS or any other libraries you are using (like Popper.js)?